# Questions asking for interpretation

Tags: discussion

As interpretations go, they can be more or less subjective. With that in mind, questions asking for them may make little sense. Of course, there has to be a however.

However, proverbs. Would you consider questions asking for interpretation of proverbs as valid? The sense of the proverbs may be obvious, and I would consider that a good question.

What about their origins, though? Since those can often be poetic, or lost in the depths of history, this can be subjective as well.

To extend this question's context a little, as an English learner, questions asking for *interpretation* help verify the understanding of the language. In ideal circumstances, the question would receive a set of different answers, evaluated via voting, through which I could compare how wrong I was.

Comment: If a proverb's meaning is not general reference, I don't see why a question about it should be off-topic, any more than a question about an unclear idiom would be. One of the first questions I asked on this site was [Meaning of "Butter is gold in the morning, silver at noon, and lead at night"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103120/meaning-of-butter-is-gold-in-the-morning-silver-at-noon-and-lead-at-night). The question drew some interesting answers and has never (to my knowledge) been challenged as off-topic. It might have helped that I was also interested in the proverb's origin.

Answer (score 3):

Questions on interpreting a foreign word or phrase into English are generally considered off-topic because they can be answered using a dictionary for that purpose.

Questions about the nuances of related words (which might arise during translation) are on-topic, provided they are asked clearly, with context, and demonstrate effort on the part of the asker beyond "they were both suggested as translations of {my foreign word}".

Questions about word/phrase usage and meaning in context are also on-topic.

Likewise, phrase or word requests are acceptable for seeking translations of foreign words and phrases (including proverbs) as long as they meet all the other requirements as well -- context, research, etc.

For more information, there are [quite a few questions](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=translation) about our policy on translation that you might want to check out.